# Alter child collections of two models in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this:

```
$merge = parents::with('children')->get();
```

which gives me:

```
  [{
  "id":1,
  "parent_name":"Robert",
  "children":[{
            "id":5,"name":"Susan","dob":"2010-11-11"},
            {"id":7,"name":"Tony","dob":"2014-12-10"}]
  }]
```

I want to add `age` into children with expected output like this:

```
  [{
  "id":1,
  "parent_name":"Robert",
  "children":[{
            "id":5,"name":"Susan","dob":"2010-11-11","age":"10"},
            {"id":7,"name":"Tony","dob":"2014-12-10","age":"7"}]
  }]
```

I tried this:

```
 return $merge->map(function ($detail) {
    $detail->age = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($detail->dob)->diffInYears();
    return $detail;});
```

it gives me:

```
  [{
  "id":1,
  "parent_name":"Robert",
  "age":0,
  "children":[{
            "id":5,"name":"Susan","dob":"2010-11-11"},
            {"id":7,"name":"Tony","dob":"2014-12-10"}]
  }]
```

I tried:

```
    return $merge->children->map(function ($detail) {
    $detail->age = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($detail->dob)->diffInYears();
    return $detail;});
```

It returns

```
Property [children] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Is there any simple way to achieve my goal?

Comment: did you try `$merge->children()->map`?

Comment: yes but returns error as well. it says `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::children does not exist.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop on each parent and its children and add new age property

```
$data = parents::with('children')->get();
        $data->each(function($parent) {
            $parent->children->each(function($child){
                $child->age = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($child->dob)->diffInYears();
            });
        });
```

what I suggest and I think is better is to add an attribute to your Model like so:

```
class modelName extends Model{
  protected $append = ['age'];

  public function getAgeAttribute(){
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->dob)->diffInYears();
  }


}
```

Comment: `Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference` it highlights the second last `});`

Comment: Excuse me, which approach you applied?

Comment: the first one. i've already made the second one and i can pull the data within the view independently. but my goal is to produce collections shown above. the expected output one.

Comment: The First one it works fine, and I just give you an example .. you have to adapt it on your own Code , the 2nd solution is the best for me because u will get always your model with age property and you don't need to merge collection or assing carbon date in your view each time

Comment: i had another variable named `children`, i removed it and retry the first one. it returns `null` on every row. while dobs are not empty.

Comment: the second one works now. it was a typo issue. i replace `$append` with `$appends` then it works

Answer (score 0):

Loop through parents and its children. Eventually calculate the age and put the value to array.

```
$merge->map(function ($mer) {
    $mer->children->map(function ($child) {
        $age = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($child->dob)->diffInYears();
        $child->age = $age;
    });
});
```

Comment: returns `Call to undefined method App\Models\children::put()`

Comment: O, it's an object. I will update my code.

Comment: If it didn't work. Then just do it like this. `$child->age = $age`

Comment: i need it to be inside the structure.